# what is purpose of IIR filter?

Tags: finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response

I am working on Digital Signal Processing. I know theory very well but I don't understand why IIR filter is used in place of FIR. What is advantage?

Comment: They are computationally more efficient and need less memory than FIR filters for comparable filter properties. Also read [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9552/4298) for some more details.

Comment: Also, sometimes the concept of "feedback" is important in a given problem. One may want a system's behavior to not just depend on the input, but also outputs at other indices. FIR filters have no feedback.